# How to use file appender with jar file?

Tags: java, logging

I use logback in my main program  .I implement the logback.xml file like so  :

```
<configuration>

  <appender name="ROLLING" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>E:\mylog.txt</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <!-- rollover daily -->
      <fileNamePattern>mylog-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.txt</fileNamePattern>
      <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
        <!-- or whenever the file size reaches 100MB -->
        <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
      </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
      <Pattern>%date{"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", UTC} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} %L - %msg%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <Pattern>%date{"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", UTC} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} %L - %msg%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <logger name="source.main.FileProcess" level="INFO" />
  <logger name="source.main.FileReadWrite" level="INFO" />
  <logger name="source.main.OperatorLoader" level="DEBUG" />
  <logger name="source.exception.ValidationException" level="INFO" />
  <logger name="source.validation.Validation" level="INFO" />


  <root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="ROLLING" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

My application work fine  .but when I convert it to a jar file File appender dose not work and logs only shows in console  .I use this statement for make a jar file  :

```
jar -cvfm app.jar manifest.txt source/main/MyApp.class
```

And content of manifest.txt file is like so  :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: source.main.FileProcess
Class-Path: slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar logback-core-1.1.3.jar logback-classic-1.1.3.jar OperatorInterface.jar
```

Do anyone know where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the path to your logback configuration when you execute your jar:

```
java -Dlogback.configurationFile=PATH_TO_FILE -jar app.jar
```

Comment: sorry if may logback.xml is in E:\ PATH_TO_FILE = E:\logback.xml ?

Comment: Yes, try -Dlogback.configurationFile=E:\logback.xml